# Cannot install rbenv version of ruby on MacOS Big Sur - Interrupted system call

Tags: macos, rbenv, macos-big-sur

rbenv is not building any version of Ruby on my Mac (Big Sur), although I get different errors depending on the version I attempt to build. For example, the commands I used and their output are below:

```
simon@Simons-MBP ~ % time rbenv install 3.0.0
Downloading openssl-1.1.1i.tar.gz...
-> https://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/e8be6a35fe41d10603c3cc635e93289ed00bf34b79671a3a4de64fcee00d5242
Installing openssl-1.1.1i...
Installed openssl-1.1.1i to /Users/simon/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0

Downloading ruby-3.0.0.tar.gz...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/3.0/ruby-3.0.0.tar.gz
Installing ruby-3.0.0...
ruby-build: using readline from homebrew

BUILD FAILED (macOS 11.2.1 using ruby-build 20210119)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/7x/tj7wsjgj4nl1g3h6sbjdrf8m0000gn/T/ruby-build.20210226164233.16496.FWB6V6
Results logged to /var/folders/7x/tj7wsjgj4nl1g3h6sbjdrf8m0000gn/T/ruby-build.20210226164233.16496.log
```

The last lines of the log file are as follows:

```
compiling inspector.c
-e:4:in `write': Interrupted system call @ rb_sysopen - failure.failed (Errno::EINTR)
        from -e:4:in `<main>'
make[2]: *** [failure.failed] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ext/-test-/cxxanyargs/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
compiling profile_frames.c
compiling empty.c
linking shared-object -test-/dln/empty.bundle
linking shared-object -test-/debug.bundle
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

Any ideas why I'm getting the **Interrupted system call** message?

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution? I faced the same issue. I've tried to use rvm, rbenv, ruby-install but got errors all the time.

Comment: It started to happen after upgrading my Mac to Big Sur.

Comment: As for now, I can't use any ruby versions manager. It's terrible.

Comment: Not the best solution, but I ended up installing ruby with `brew install ruby` for now.

Answer (score 2):

Pause your antivirus and try again. It worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried this and it still didn't work. 

Comment: Avast blocked me (required for VPN for work). I tried installing with brew first but then saw this and it worked. Thanks!